# how to check if a float number is an integer in cpp?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer

For example 14.2 is not an integer but 14.0 is an integer in a mathematical perspective. What I've tried to do is the following, let n be a `long double`, so to check if it's an integer I compared it to its integer form:

```
if (n == (int) n) 
{
    // n is an integer
}
```

It all looks perfect but when I applied it, it didn't work, and when i debugged the program I discovered that the `long double` number is never a whole number; it's not 14.0 instead it's 14.0000000000000000000002, the last 2 is added by the compiler.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: This is just floating-point errors, which are also much more prominent on a `float` as opposed to a `double`. There's ways of checking how close you are (e.g. `abs(myFloat - ((int) myFloat)) < SOME_THRESHOLD` (where that threshold may be small, e.g. `0.00000001`), but overall you will almost always have a little bit of "mess" to look out for in this case. This is particularly true since `14` cannot be represented by a `float`.

Comment: `long double` (or `double`) can represent a huge array of numbers. But they can represent very few exactly. Your program just has to deal with that imprecision.

Comment: XY Problem maybe: why would you want to know if a floating point number is a mathematical integer?

Comment: @Rogue "`14` cannot be represented by a `float`" What? Really?

Comment: @YSC because i'm trying to test if the floating part of a number inputed by user is binairy or not in order to convert it to hexadecimale number later, what i want to do is to multiplay the floating part by 10 until it became integeral (now i can't know when to stop multiplaying since i can't know exacly that the floating part has turned into integeral part) in order to test if it's in binairy then convert it, i want to do all the steps manually without having to use built in functions of converting in order to train my brain for problem solving.

Comment: @NathanPierson I just double checked, in fact it can be exactly represented (it's more often the case that a whole number cannot be). It's likely the result of a math operation that lead to the `14.0000...`. `14` in floating point would have an exponent value of `10000010` and a digits value of `11000000000000000000000`, aka the familiar binary representation of `1110`.

Comment: There might be better way to proceed then. Just to check _"i'm trying to test if the floating part of a number inputed by user is binairy or not "_: for instance if the user inputs `563.10011` this is supposed to pass your test and `16.021` should not? Can you please [edit] your question to explain your goal with concrete examples for a passing and failing values?

Comment: @YSC i already have the code that test the integeral part, that's mean if the user input 563.10011, it's gonna get rejected, btw i found solution to it now, thanks for help.

Comment: @Rogue thanks, i fixed my code based on this idea, really appreciate it.
abs(myFloat - ((int) myFloat)) < SOME_THRESHOLD (where that threshold may be small, e.g. 0.00000001)

Comment: Ok, [edit] your question and I'll answer it.

Comment: @YSC i found solution to my problem, thank you.

Comment: What fix? 14.00000000000002 is not an integer, so the computer is telling you the right answer - there is no problem.

Comment: What about using something like `std::modf()` and checking whether the decimal portion is (close to) 0?

Comment: `14.0L` can be exactly represented as a `long double`.  But `long double ld = 0.1L; long double xiv = ld * 140.0L;` may have some funny business in the fiddly bits end of the spectrum of the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest approach is to use `floor()` and not concern yourself with casting to integer types which makes the false assumption that there will be no overflow in converting a floating-point value to integer.
For large floats that's obviously not true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // This is where the overloaded versions of floor() are.


bool is_whole(double d){
    return d==floor(d);
}

int main() {
    double x{14.0};
    double y{14.2};
    double z{-173.5};
    
    std::cout << is_whole(14.0) << '\n';    
    std::cout << is_whole(14.2) << '\n';
    std::cout << is_whole(-123.4) << '\n';
    std::cout << is_whole(-120394794.0) << '\n';
    std::cout << is_whole(-120394794.44) << '\n';
    std::cout << is_whole(3681726.0) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
1
0
0
1
0
1
```